# GAZEBO 1.5 NEW VERSION new features?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, i was waitin' for a new version of gazebo, and i need to know if in these new version it's possible deformation of objects.

thnks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1724/gazebo-1.5-new-version-new-features?/) by [monidiaz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/124/monidiaz/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Deformable objects will not be in Gazebo 1.5.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0